# Update Error in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

Am using laravel 4.2 and i want to an update.

//-------IN USERCONTROLLER-------///

```
public function getUpdatepage() {

    $user = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id->get());
    View::make('users.updatepage')->with('user', $user);

}
```

//------IN THE BROWSER------//

It says "Trying to get a property of non-object"

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code.

This line

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id->get());
```

should be this:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As i assume id is the primary key of the user table.try this

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
```

if not

```
$user = User::whereId(Auth::user()->id);
```

Comment: The error keeps persisting. this is my Route....=> Route::get('updatepage', array('uses' => 'UserController@getupdatepage'));

Comment: try this

$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->get();
Or
$user = User::whereId(Auth::user()->id);